# Why is my formula for converting minutes in to days hours and minutes returning incorrect results and how can I fix?

Tags: c++, integer, integer-division

I am new to programming and cannot figure out why my program is returning the wrong answer. We are supposed to convert a given amount of minutes (in this case 1540) into days hours and minutes. The correct output should be 1 day 1 hour and 20 minutes but I am getting 40 minutes instead while everything else is correct. This also doesn't happen with all inputted minutes, for some problems it also returns the correct answer which confuses me more. The problem is clearly the formula I am using but I don't understand why it returns 40 minutes instead of 20 in this given example. I left out everything but the formula and the number of minutes that I need to be converted.

```
int totalTime = 1540;

daysWatched = totalTime / minutesInDay; //1440 minutes in a day
totalTime %= minutesInDay;
hoursWatched = totalTime / minutesInHour; //60 minutes in an hour
totalTime %= minutesInHour;
minutesWatched = totalTime;
```

Comment: *"I don't understand why it returns 40 minutes instead of 20 in this given example"* - A day has 1440 minutes, so take away a day, that's 100 minutes remaining. Take away an hour (60 minutes), thats 40 minutes remaining. In other words, its right; your expectation of 20 is what's wrong.

Comment: If you have access to the standard C++ library with its date and time classes, it's worth learning how to use those. There are often unexpected "gotchas" with time operations (especially non-obvious things, like integer overflows), and the library handles them properly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct output is 1 day 1 hour and 40 min. First, when you divide 1540/1440 you will get 1, and then when you use 1540%1440 you will get 100 which is 60min=1 hour and 40 min left that's why the output is 40, not 20 if you think that the output should be 1 day 1 hour and 20 min then your totalTime=1520, not 1540.